# Dart lang, multiple extends generic

Tags: generics, dart

is it possible to have multiple extends in "generics" in dart lang? 
some thing like this:

```
  class myApp<T extends String, num> {
     T getLowerCase(T userInput) {
        return userInput.toLowerCase();
   }

     T addAll(T userInput) {
        return userInput + 10;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found it! I have to change my code this way:

```
class myApp<T extends String, N extends num> {
    T getLowerCase(T userInput) {
    print(userInput.toLowerCase());
  }

    N addAll(N userInput) {
    print(userInput + 10);
  }
}
```

(thanks java!)

Comment: But if anyone has a tip for guidance, please tell me